# Can a Python Command be executed when a button is pressed in a Flash Program

Tags: python, function, flash, actionscript, command

I am currently building a flash program (swf file) and I already have functions and commands created in Python. Is their a way to import my Python Commands into Flash CC and for example: execute my Python command when a button is pressed in my Flash Program?

I have already searched the internet and Stackoverflow.com for an answer. I am aware of pyamf but I do not know how to use it and I really don't think it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to run an external code in AS3 is to use AIR , for this matter you need to compile you python code and put exe file some where and using native process run it and communicate with it. this code may help you more.

_exepath part is address of your exe file compiled from python code.

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.NativeProcessExitEvent;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.events.Event;

public class ProcessRequest extends EventDispatcher {

    private var _np:NativeProcess;
    private var _npi:NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    private var _args:Vector.<String>;
    private var exePath:String;
    private var _windowsPath:String;

    public var _output:String;

    public function ProcessRequest(_exePath:String) {
        exePath = _exePath;
    }

    public function process(input_arg:Vector.<String>):void {
        _args = input_arg;
        _process();
    }

    private function _process():void {
        _npi = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        _npi.executable = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(exePath);
        _npi.arguments = _args;

        _np = new NativeProcess();
        _np.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
        _np.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
        _np.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
        _np.start(_npi);
    }

    private function onOutputData(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        _output = String(_np.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(_np.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));
        dispatchEvent(new Event("OutputData"));
    }

    private function onErrorData(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        _output = String(_np.standardError.readUTFBytes(_np.standardError.bytesAvailable));
        dispatchEvent(new Event("ErrorData"));
    }

    private function onExit(e:NativeProcessExitEvent):void {
        _np.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
        _np.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
        _np.removeEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
        _npi = null;
        _np = null;
        _args = null;
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }

    public function Cancel():void {
        _np.exit(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain how to use this code further. I am new to Flash CC and have never run an swf file with code before. And will all the commands from my .py file be transferred to the .swf file/project now.

Comment: you need to make a as file and copy this code there. then import that file into your project and also your executable file from python. then give your .exe file address to the constructor of this class and then call process function with what argument your exe file needs